# laravel, how to use controller store Action to save objects in cascade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working on an app that requires multi-authentication, I used creative-tim preset for the dashboard (providing that creative-tim uses the "User" name for storing users in the dashboard) I created on top of that an Admin table that has a one-to-one relationship with the User table, and created the appropriate middleware to restrict access to my "Admin-only" views and used tinker to create an Admin and link it to a test everything.
the problem now is that I want to automate the creation of the admin relationship with the user through a registration form, only problem is, the creative-tim template I'm using doesn't follow the laravel docs so I couldn't understand it and I don't know how to link an "Admin" model to the created "User".

Here's a part of the database/model:
User(id,name,email,email_verified_at,password,rememberToken,timestamps)
Admin(id,user_id,role,timestamps)

the way they used is (obviously store) but they used a UserRequest and User Object, I tried doing this:

```
        $Admin = new Admin();
        $Admin->role="Admin";
        $Admin->user_id = $model->id;
        $Admin->save();
```

here's the original function I found

```
    public function store(UserRequest $request, User $model)
    {
        $model->create($request->merge(['password' =>Hash::make($request->get('password'))])->all());
  return redirect()->route('user.index')->withStatus(__('User successfully created.'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a solution for the problem (that wasn't my preferred) so I created a user normally and got the id, used it to create an Admin, Works Perfectly after validation

```
public function store(UserRequest $request, User $model)
    {
         //validation parameters

         $item = new User();
        $item->name = request('name');
        $item->email = request('email');
        $item->password = Hash::make(request('password'));
        $item->save();

        $admin = new Admin();
        $admin->user_id = $item->id;
        $admin->role ="SuperAdmin";
        $admin->save();
        return redirect()->route('user.index')->withStatus(__('User successfully created.'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started PHP
And in the first project (RSS)
I succeeded with the help of this post
https://github.com/ganjali89/RSSproject.git

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.